Sum values in repeated BigQuery field
I am trying to figure out how to sum values from a repeated key/value record in bigquery to generate some aggregate data. For example if I had a simplified purchase table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.purchases (
  id STRING,
  purchase_time DATE,
  store_id INT64,
  purchase_total INT64
  cart
    ARRAY<
      STRUCT<
        item STRING,
        quantity INT64>>
);

I can easily sum the hourly purchases with a query like:
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0 + 3600 * DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(`purchase_time`) - 0, 3600)) AS hour_start, store_id, sum(purchase_total) AS store_purchase_total 
FROM foo.purchases
WHERE purchase_time > @startTime AND purchase_time < @endTime
GROUP BY hour_start, store_id

I can also do something like:
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(0 + 3600 * DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(`purchase_time`) - 0, 3600)) AS hour_start, store_id, sum(purchase_total) AS store_purchase_total,
IF (ARRAY_LENGTH(cart) > 0, crt.item, 'unknown') as sold_item, SUM(IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(cart) > 0), crt.quantity, 0)) as sold_quantity
FROM foo.purchases
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(foo.purchases.cart) as crt
WHERE purchase_time > @startTime AND purchase_time < @endTime
GROUP BY hour_start, store_id, sold_item

The above query will get me multiple rows per store per hour, which I can dedupe in code but I'd much rather be able to get this data back in a single row with a repeated struct similar to the original table structure.
